# Adjustable server-side Reactive Variable - Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, meteor

I have been stuck on this problem for many hours, and I'm sure the fix is easy but I can't grasp it!

I'm developing an app that has a marquee text at the bottom of the screen that scrolls.

I have a reactive variable that I want to change via UI input.
However, it only changes on the client side, other devices cannot see the changed variable.

Worth noting that I did try to put it in a collection, and it worked, but the marquee animation package does not work with collections.

My client main.js

```
myMessage= new ReactiveVar('Welcome to the app');
```

and the html to display it in my body.html

```
  <div style="color: white;" class="ui center aligned container">
    <div class='marquee'>{{myMessage}}</div>
  </div>
```

body.js helper

```
   globalMessage () {
     return globalMessage.get();
   },
```

The form that should change it .js events

```
 'submit form': function(event){

           event.preventDefault();
           var newMsg = event.target.newMsg.value;
           myMessage.set(newMsg);

    }
```

Can someone point me to the right direction? It's doing my head in. 
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Is this `marquee` value should be the same for all users/clients?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants a global marquee. He's on the right track with the collection.

Comment: I wouldn't mind using a collection, it just wouldn't do the animation with {#each} statements. Is there a way to return only the first collection item's variable, without having to use {each}  statement in the HTML?